# Getting return value from Javascript in C# Webbrowser control WPF

Tags: c#, javascript, wpf, webbrowser-control, ihtmldocument2

I made JavaScript injection into WebBrowser control in C# `(System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser)`
such that, `<C#>`

```
IHTMLDocument2 webdoc = (IHTMLDocument2)webBrowser1.Document;
string var = File.ReadAllText("C:/.../Resources/script.txt");
object retVal = webdoc.parentWindow.execScript(var, "Jscript");
```

and the JavaScript file script.txt is,

```
var headID = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js'
headID.appendChild(newScript)

$('body').bind('click',function(e){
    var domsArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++){
        for (var j = 0; j < 15; j++){
            if (document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX+i, e.clientY+j) && (jQuery.inArray(document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX+i, e.clientY+j), domsArray) < 0)){
            domsArray.push(document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX+i, e.clientY+j));
            }if (document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX-i, e.clientY+j) && (jQuery.inArray(document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX-i, e.clientY+j), domsArray) < 0)){
            domsArray.push(document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX-i, e.clientY+j));
            }if (document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX+i, e.clientY-j) && (jQuery.inArray(document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX+i, e.clientY-j), domsArray) < 0)){
            domsArray.push(document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX+i, e.clientY-j));
            }if (document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX-i, e.clientY-j) && (jQuery.inArray(document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX-i, e.clientY-j), domsArray) < 0)){
            domsArray.push(document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX-i, e.clientY-j));
        }}}
for (var p = 0; p < domsArray.length; p++){
    alert(domsArray[p].href);
}});
```

What it does is, whenever a user clicks on any point in webbrowser page, it collects the href near around that point.

I wanted to return the href array, to my C# so that I can create buttons with those links.

However, when I tried,

```
Console.WriteLine(retVal);
```

It didn't print anything on console.
Even after I cast them into things like string or int with other dummy return values, it didn't print anything.
Am I getting correct return?
Is there any way that I can test the output return from javascript?

Comment: Have you tried checking the value of `retVal` while debugging to see whether it is null or has a value? If it does have a value, then you should be able to see the data type, properties, etc... while debugging to get a better idea of what you need to modify in order to get the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be a scope issue.  Have you tried moving the

```
var domsArray = [];
```

outside the (above) the

```
$('body').bind('click',function(e){  ....
```

function?  such as

```
var domsArray = [];
$('body').bind('click',function(e){

    for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++){  < ... etc ....>
```

also I think you are missing a couple of semicolons (lines 3 & 4 of script.txt) though that probably shouldn't make a difference.